# Unable to find Boot Screen to install Ubuntu , with windows 8 installed

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu, with Windows 8 installed on my
system.

But I am unable to get the GRUB boot screen to select the Operating System, as it is UEFI secure boot
protected. Can anyone help me on this one?

I am looking for installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 (Dual-Boot.)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What steps did you followed exactly? Are you able to get install screen? I am confused with your explenation: Did you maneged to finish installation or you are not able get install screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you have the UEFI secure boot, then you need to download Ubuntu 64-bit. It is recommended for Windows 8 and will bypass secure boot. To download it, just go to the [Ubuntu Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) page, but this time, select 64-bit instead of 32-bit. Then download and install as normal. If you want to dual-boot, it will ask. (Run alongside Windows 8.)

Hope this helps!